Great literature on discrete dynamical systems and/or qualitative theory of difference equations
I am asking for the great literature on topics of discrete dynamical systems and/or qualitative theory of difference equations especially aimed on pure mathematicians. Could you please give me some good references.

I feel like I already gave this advice, but I want to recommend P. Kurka's Topological and Symbolic Dynamics (2003). The first $\approx$ 100 of pages are a really great general introduction to topological dynamics in discrete time setting, developed through Akin's topological relations. Then symbolic dynamics is developed effectively and at a quite deeper level than usual in dynamical systems textbooks.
It's far more readable than Akin's General topology of DS and just as rigorous (though not as general). Only weak point in my opinion: it has not many exercises, and some of them are quite difficult and given without hints.

Great recommendation, thanks. I have just been looking for a source on topological dynamics and this seems like the most well written one i’ve come across so far.

Thank you for the great recommendation!

You both are welcome!

For discrete dynamical systems, I think you can hardly do better than the book by Katok and Hasselblatt, Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems.
Unfortunately, I know of no good reference for difference equations.

Thank you for super reference!

Glad I could help! @OleksandrLiubimov
